# Not operator or Strict comparison on false?

Tags: php, if-statement, code-standards, psr-12

What's the best practice for writing if-statement on boolean value?

```
function foo(boolean $bar)
{
    if ($bar === false) // ...
    // or
    if (!$bar) // ...
}
```

With a Not operator it's more compact, but you may not notice this operator while reading a code.

And why do some coders write in Yoda style like `false === $bar` ?

Comment: There is no merit for the code in being compact. The code must be readable, not "compact"

Comment: In this particular case it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious reason is in case you don't have Boolean return value and need to differentiate between other falsy values (0, false, null, "0", etc). For example when using `strrpos()` you might get `false` which is different than `0`.

As for the ugly Yoda style, that is to avoid mistakes such as `$bar = false` instead of `$bar == false`. You would get error if you tried `false = $bar` and notice it straight away.